# remove of null object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

how can I not release data if two attributes are empty?

```
const fork = [
  { from: 'client', msg: null, for: null },
  { from: 'client', msg: '2222222222222', for: null },
  { from: 'server', msg: 'wqqqqqqqqqqqq', for: 'data/64.....' }
];

console.log(message)
```

These are three sample entries, in fact they are always replenished. And there are more.

I need to do this, if two attributes are empty then do not send if somewhere null then do not release this value

```
const fork = [
  { from: 'client', msg: null, for: null }, // remove line full
  { from: 'client', msg: '2222222222222', for: null }, // remove for
  { from: 'server', msg: null, for: 'data/64.....' } // remove msg
];
console.log(message)
```

Comment: What do you mean with *two entries are empty*? Do you mean `null` with *empty*?

Comment: @Mushroomator I want to remove all data from the column if there is zero for example: `msg: null` <- remove field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const fork = [
  { from: 'client', msg: null, for: null },
  { from: 'client', msg: '2222222222222', for: null },
  { from: 'server', msg: 'wqqqqqqqqqqqq', for: 'data/64.....' }
];

const result = fork.map(item => {
  if (Object.values(item).filter(i => i === null).length > 1) return null
  const obj = {...item}
  for (const key in obj) {
    if (obj[key] === null) {
      delete obj[key]
    }
  }
  return obj
}).filter(item => item !== null)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could filter the array and map the rest.

```js
const
    fork = [{ from: 'client', msg: null, for: null }, { from: 'client', msg: '2222222222222', for: null }, { from: 'server', msg: 'wqqqqqqqqqqqq', for: 'data/64.....' }];
    result = fork
        .filter(o => ['msg', 'for'].some(k => o[k] !== null))
        .map(o => Object.fromEntries(Object
            .entries(o)
            .filter(([, v]) => v !== null)
        ));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `reduce` method

```js
const fork = [
  { from: "client", msg: null, for: null },
  { from: "client", msg: "2222222222222", for: null },
  { from: "server", msg: "wqqqqqqqqqqqq", for: "data/64....." },
];

const res = fork.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const obj = { from: curr.from };
  ["msg", "for"].forEach((key) => (curr[key] !== null && (obj[key] = curr[key])));
  return Object.keys(obj).length > 1 ? acc.concat(obj) : acc;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```